# How to understand how hasNextInt is defined if I use two variables

Tags: java

How is `hasNextInt` defined with two variables? For example, if I count two `int` variables and I need to add them if they are both `int`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int v1,v2;
    boolean check = true;
    while(check)
    {
        try
        {
        v1 = input.nextInt();
        v2 = input.nextInt();
        sum += v1+v2;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println(sum);
            check = false;
        }
    }
    }

}
```

I tried to solve this problem through `hasNextInt`, but finally gave up and decided through `try... catch`

Comment: You can't check "ahead" with `Scanner`'s API.  You have to check one, then the next.

Comment: [Scanner.hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) checks  if there is another token, regardless of how the token might be interpreted. [~.hasNextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) checks if there is another token **and** that token can be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: If you require tokens to be paired, use `hasNext()` or `hasNextInt()` to check for the first. If true, use `nextInt()` then use `hasNext()` or `hasNextInt()` to check for the second. You'll have to decide how an unpaired token should be handled.

Comment: What do you mean by a token

Comment: A `Scanner` is *A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.  // A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.*  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I understand you, but what is a token in simple language. Im just new to programming

Comment: What problems did you encounter when you tried `hasNextInt()`, if you want us to help you with that, then show the code and explain what happened.

Comment: @nikk0nikk0ni A "token" is a sequence one or more characters from the input that has some meaning as a group and cannot be divided into smaller pieces. These are like the "words" of a language. For example, the string "123" can be considered a single token that represents the number 123. On the other hand "12+34" might be interpreted as three tokens, the numbers 12 and 34 and the + operator. To understand this in more detail, I recommend that you read about so-called "string parsing".

Comment: additional info to previous comment: by default the `Scanner` separates the tokens by one or more whitespaces (including SPACE, TAB, NEWLINE) - so, for example `"123  abc "` will result in two tokens `"123"` and `"abc"` (the delimiter [pattern] can be changed)

Comment: Thank you 4 explanation

Comment: "but what is a token in simple language" each individual thing that you read from the Scanner. The *purpose* of the Scanner is to split up the input into tokens. This kind of information is [easy to search for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=programming+concepts+token), by the way.

Answer (score -1):

"check = false;" is in the wrong place. Your code ends after an exception in an infinite loop. After the exception, one possibility would be to create a New Scanner Object. You should set "check" to false in the try block.

It would look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int v1,v2;
        boolean check = true;

        while(check == true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Write the first number: ");
                v1 = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Write the second number: ");
                v2 = input.nextInt();
                sum += v1 + v2;
                System.out.println("The result of " + v1 + " + " + v2 + " is " + sum);
                check = false;
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
            {
                System.out.println("The input is not valid! \nPlease use valid integer values!\n");
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
            }
        }
    }

}
```